# Pre-caching limitations and reliability in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, offline-map

The latest version of the Google Maps application bundled with Android allows me to pre-cache map areas. Each time a pre-cache a point it saves the map in a 10 km hamming radius of that point.

I'm about to take a long vacation in various destination. Can I pre-cache those destinations and reliably use Google Maps there without data connection? Is there a limit to how many areas I can pre-cache (aside from the obvious memory required)? Is the map data guarantee to remain after a few weeks or months, or does it expire after some time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of areas you can pre-cache is limited by the amount of system storage you have available.  It is important to note that the cache is stored in system storage, not the SD card.  Also, the stored data is the base map tiles and landmarks.  You will not be able to get directions based on this downloaded data, but you can browse it offline and track your current location.

The cached data expires and is deleted automatically after 30 days.  If you are not able to refresh your offline data in that time, you may be in trouble.

More data on the feature is available on the [Official Google Blog post](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/download-map-area-added-to-labs-in.html).

Comment: Well I just checked and it turns out the number of cached areas is limited to 10, regardless of how much storage I have remaining on the SD card :\

Comment: To those coming across this now, note that the Google Maps app now offers Offline Areas. While similar to caching, it offers more features including directions (obviously not with current traffic information though!) However, they currently do still expire after 30 days.