# Are there maps that I can download to a PC and later transfer to the android phone?

Tags: gps, maps

I notice that many maps vendor such as Google require user to download offline map using their android phone. At the worst case, the user need to setup internet connection point in which the android phone will use the PC's internet to retrieve those offline map.

So, **my question is** - are there really pure offline map that I can first download to my PC and later transfer to the android phone? (It would be better if the offline map can also be view inside the PC too. Meaning that the offline map can be used on multiple devices - Portability!)

Comment: Search for TrekBuddy. Related Qs: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30369/how-to-import-gps-coordinates-track-for-using-offline and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/how-to-get-maps-for-off-line-usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) which works well with offline maps (OSM). Download offline map(s) once and after that no internet connection is required to use them.

You can download the .obf-file of your location from this [list of offline maps](http://download.osmand.net/rawindexes/list.php). Or use the  app to download .obf files directly to your device.

Answer (score 2):

There's an excellent mapping app called Locus ([website](http://www.locusmap.eu/) | app [free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus) | [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus.pro)) which has been around for ages and offers a whole lot more features than Google Maps.  It supports offline map caching and it looks like you can download vector maps from [here](http://www.vectormaps4locus.eu/content/vector-maps), topographical maps from [here](http://www.4umaps.eu/mountain-bike-hiking-bicycle-outdoor-topographic-map.htm).

Having downloaded one of the vector maps, it seems to be using OSM files, which have a whole load of [viewers for the desktop](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Desktop).

Comment: I tried one - JOSM which is listed in your last link but when I open the OSM files, I only see lots and lots of dots even though I can see the country shape. Maybe my next question to ask would be which viewers is best recommended for opening OSM files (and I believe that I might need to ask in the SuperUser Stackexchange.)