# Easily record GPS coordinates in OpenStreetMap

Tags: gps, osmand

I live in Argentina and use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) since the maps are really accurate in that area.

I travel in a specific area with my Android smartphone using GPS. In that area mainly I like to save GPS coordinates in my map (my clients) and make notes to them. Additionally, I would like to add roads that are not recorded in OpenStreetMap yet, but that is not really necessary.

Currently I use the [OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) app on my phone. It contains offline maps, which is important since I don't have any Internet connection out there. I can record favorites, but I can't really make many notes to them, like some kind of history of my visits. And I can't extend the map of unknown roads with that app.

Is there a better way to achieve that?

I would like to use the favorites to see where I have to make my visits next and what would be the best route for that.

Comment: With [Trekbuddy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.trekbuddy.midlet&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC50cmVrYnVkZHkubWlkbGV0Il0.) (see [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/how-to-have-my-phone-guide-me-through-a-specific-route/38260#38260) Q/A) you can add comments like notes to a way points that you would like to visit. Trekbuddy uses maps prepared with MOBAC and is quite similar to OsmAnd.

Answer (score 3):

[OsmTracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.guillaumin.android.osmtracker&hl=en) will meet your requirements. It can upload the [GPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) tracks directly to OpenStreetMap, but I prefer using [JOSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOSM) to upload the data.

Comment: I forgot.to mention that I need a tool with offline maps.

Answer (score 2):

Use **several different apps**:

[MapsWithMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps&hl=en) is awesome for viewing OpenStreetMap offline. You can download whole countries, and see them in a very fluid interface.

[OSMTracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.guillaumin.android.osmtracker&hl=en) is a good basic GPS tracing app, with buttons for taking quick notes of various kinds (do the actual OpenStreetMap editing later when you get home).

[Vespucci](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vespucci) is a more full-featured OpenStreetMap editor which would allow you to add roads. I could be wrong, but I think it's the [only Android app](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android#OpenStreetMap_editing_features) which supports full geometry editing. That's always going to be a bit fiddly to do on a phone anyway though, and I don't find Vespucci very easy to use (I prefer to take notes and then edit at home).

Those are some of my personal preferences at the moment, but people are developing/improving these apps all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [osmeditor4android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blau.android) does what you're looking for. Functionality includes:

- create, edit new nodes & ways
- append nodes to existing ways
- create, edit tags
- up/download to OSM server
- highlight unnamed highways & ways/nodes with TODOs

If it somehow doesn't do what you want, the [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) has a nice chart comparing a number of Android apps.

Comment: The problem with vespucci is that I cant load the complete area at once. It is too big for that.