# Download Region or State for offline Map

Tags: google-maps, offline

Is it possible to download an entire state offline map for Google Maps via a 3rd party app?

I know that if you download the offline map through Google Maps it allows you to download an area roughly equivalent to a city. Currently I've been stitching the offline maps together but its a very long and tedious process.

I'm not concerned about size or bandwidth that it may use.

Comment: The reason why there are no apps to do this is that it's not allowed by google maps terms of service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with [Maps (+)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coderminus.maps) (or its ad-financed free version [Maps (-) Offline Navigation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coderminus.maps)). This app was developed for exactly this purpose (even before Google Labs introduced the "pre-caching" feature). I never tried it myself, but the comments look promising as well.

[image: Maps(+)] [image: Maps(+)]
<sup>Maps (+) (Source: [Google Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coderminus.maps); click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Nope - there is no way at this time of writing to download maps for Google Maps other than using Google Maps itself. If it denies downloading due to selection of large area, there is no way to do it other then using another app.

If you would like to use a different mapping app, still using Google's offline maps or other maps like [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), you may try using [Trekbuddy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.trekbuddy.midlet&hl=en).  To know more about it, you can read about it from its [wiki page](http://www.trekbuddy.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) and/or see these questions:

1. [How to have my phone guide me through a specific route](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/how-to-have-my-phone-guide-me-through-a-specific-route/38260#38260)
2. [How to get maps for off-line usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/how-to-get-maps-for-off-line-usage)
3. [How to import GPS coordinates track for using offline](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30369/how-to-import-gps-coordinates-track-for-using-offline/30526#30526)

Answer (score 1):

I use Here maps for precisely the reason that Google only allows downloading a city or surrounding region. Here maps allows downloading of entire states/provinces for offline use with GPS but there is no street/terrain view.