# Use Google Maps maps in Maverick

Tags: maps

How can I save Google Maps tiles so I can use them in Maverick offline?
I tried Mobile Atlas Creator, but it seems it does not have Google Map as a map source.

Comment: What's "Maverick"?

Comment: @AlEverett Probably this one: http://codesector.com/maverick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MOBile Atlas Creator (MOBAC)](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) has support for Google Maps till 1.9Beta (the last stable version is 1.8).

It can be downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/robertprojects/downloads/detail?name=Mobile%20Atlas%20Creator%201.8.zip&can=2).

Using MOBAC instead of MapsOn has the following significant advantages.

1. Since the download happens in the computer rather in phone, large area downloads are quite possible.
2. Multiple zoom levels can be downloaded and even multiple maps (like Google Terrain in one and regular Google Maps in other) can be stored in layers. See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31825/multiple-zoom-levels-without-multiple-tile-layers-rmpas-mobac/31828#31828) answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Install [MapsOn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coderminus.maps) by coderminus.

Go to `Menu > More > Preferences > Configure Maps` and set `/sdcard/maverick/tiles/Google/` or `/storage/sdcard0/maverick/tiles/Google/` as the path for the tiles of Google Maps. Now you can use the "Cache area" feature of MapsOn to download the tiles of selected areas.

Since they are stored in the Maverick folder, they are used by Maverick if you select "Google" as the map source. This also works for other map sources if you adapt the corresponding paths in MapsOn.

Comment: @Naranyanan: MapsOn allows to download multiple zoom levels (that's exactly what "Cache area" is for). It has (in my opinion) the huge advantage that you do *not* need a PC, from which the tiles still have to be transferred to the phone. Rather the tiles are readily available and one can also download missing tiles on the go. Finally, download is usually surprisingly fast and reliable, even for large areas. I, at least, had many more problems with MOBAC, which I also found inconvenient to handle - partially because of the transfer to the phone. Therefore I stopped using it.